# UICollectionViewDropDelegate wrong destination index path in `dropSessionDidUpdate`

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, drag-and-drop, uikit

I'm trying to implement Drag & Drop in this long narrow collection view:
[image: UICollectionView]

It has horizontal layout with cells and sections of different size.

Drag interaction works well, but I noticed a problem in [UICollectionViewDropDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdropdelegate):

```
func collectionView(
    _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
    dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession,
    withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?)
    -> UICollectionViewDropProposal {

    if let destination = destinationIndexPath {
        print(destination) // Prints WRONG index path!!!
        return UICollectionViewDropProposal(
            operation: .move, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath
        )
    }

    return UICollectionViewDropProposal(
        operation: .cancel, intent: .unspecified
    )
}
```

Wrong destination index path is passed to `collectionView(_:dropSessionDidUpdate:withDestinationIndexPath:)`.
Because of that I can't correctly determine the section and decide whether the drop is available there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So, it's a bug of UIKit. The correct destination index path may be calculated as following:

```
func collectionView(
    _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
    dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession,
    withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?)
    -> UICollectionViewDropProposal {

    // Calculating location in view
    let location = session.location(in: collectionView)
    var correctDestination: IndexPath?

    // Calculate index inside performUsingPresentationValues
    collectionView.performUsingPresentationValues {
        correctDestination = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: location)
    }

    guard let destination = correctDestination else {
        return UICollectionViewDropProposal(
            operation: .cancel, intent: .unspecified
        )
    }

    // check destination 
    // ...
}
```

To fix this bug, first, I tried to use the combination of `location(in:)` and `indexPathForItem(at:)`. The resulting index path was equal to `destinationIndexPath` provided by the delegate method. Why? My attention was drawn by [UIDataSourceTranslating](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatasourcetranslating). It's a protocol allowing collection and table views to show placeholder cells for drag & drop without changing the actual data source. And when the drag & drop interaction ends that placeholders are easily removed. So, I made an assumption that

1. `destinationIndexPath` is calculated with help of `indexPathForItem(at:)`
2. It ignores the placeholders created by UIDataSourceTranslating, which is a bug

Then I tried to wrap `indexPathForItem(at:)` into `performUsingPresentationValues(_:)` and the received index path was correct!

Comment: I reported the bug to Apple (FB7290341).

Comment: Unfortunately, every second time this workaround gives the wrong index. If I drag fast to a section which wasn't visible, I get the indexpath of the previous section. Tried to disable prefetching and set `collectionView.reorderingCadence = .slow` — nothing helps. Is it possible to imitate a delay somehow?

Comment: @AlexeyChekanov, 1) I don't know how to help you, better ask a question specific for your particular collection view, because I have no such problem. 2) Are you following me? You recently answered my another question.

Comment: No, I’m not following. Just a coincidence :-) Probably we are both working on the same collection view problems.